# Mobile carrier detection without IP address

Tags: jsp, mobile, ip, carrier

Is it possible to read a mobile device's carrier info with JSP or any other server side language? Detecting mobile carrier with IP address is not an option since I want to target users that use wi-fi as well.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, from the server's perspective you will only see the mobile device as an IP, be that over GSM or Wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s not possible. Maybe it could exist some special operator API, although I don´t know for WIFI users.

For GSM connection you could use IPs or look at HTTP headers. Sometimes operators inject [particular](http://certificateerror.blogspot.com.es/search?q=operators%20http) [values](http://mobiforge.com/developing/blog/useful-x-headers).